# Differential equation $x'=11x -x^2 -24$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-fractions

Getting stuck finding $x(t)$ on the differential equation:
$dx/dt = 11x -x^2 -24$ with
$x(0)=5$.

So my work so far is:
$dx/(11x-x^2-24) = dt$

Using partial fractions $A(x-3) + B(x-8) = 1$, so $A = 1/5$, $B=-1/5$
This gives me the integral: $\int(1/(x-8)-1/(x-3)) dx = 5dt$

$t+c = \ln(x-8)-\ln(x-3)$

$t+c = \ln((x-8)/(x-3))$

$Ce^t = (x-8)/(x-3)$

I know $C$ is $-3/2$.

How do I get this in terms of $x(t)$? I keep getting stuck on this step when solving differential equations and I'm hoping can help me with this specific step.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you seemed to have mixed up your signs; partial fraction decomposition gives us that:
$$
\frac{1}{11x-x^2-24} = \frac{-1/5}{x-8} + \frac{1/5}{x-3}
$$

---

Cross-multiply, bring the $x$ terms together, factor out the $x$, then divide through:
\begin{align*}
\frac{3e^t}{2} &= \frac{x - 8}{x - 3} \\
3xe^t - 9e^t &= 2x - 16 \\
3xe^t - 2x &= 9e^t - 16 \\
x(3e^t - 2) &= 9e^t - 16 \\
x(t) &= \frac{9e^t - 16}{3e^t - 2} \\
\end{align*}